# Echo variable on each iteration of while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, echo

I'm trying to echo the information/variables for each line of an alarmfile (named critical), using `while read line` to get each line of the alarmfile (might be a lot of lines on critical file):

```
while read line
do
{
s=`grep -Po '(?<=(sender:)).*' critical| cut -d ',' -f1` 
t=`grep -Po '(?<=(time:)).*' critical| cut -d '.' -f1` 
d=`grep -Po '(?<=(.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.1.8:)).*' critical| cut -d ',' -f1` 
echo "Sender: $s" >>critical_body
echo "Time: $t" >>critical_body
echo "Description: $d" >>critical_body
}
done < critical
```

The output i need is to get it structured like below:

```
Sender:  xyz1
Time:  2021/08/11 22:14:19
Description: Lost communication with device

Sender: xyz2
Time: 2021/08/13 15:58:02
Description: Memory usage is above normal: 10% free
```

But i get the following, it seems that the variables values are printed all in one iteration separated with a `/n`  and not one by one as i want.

```
Sender:  xyz1
 xyz2
Time:  2021/08/11 22:14:19
 2021/08/13 15:58:02
Description: Lost communication with device
Memory usage is above normal: 10% free
Sender:  xyz1
 xyz2
Time:  2021/08/11 22:14:19
 2021/08/13 15:58:02
Description: Lost communication with device
Memory usage is above normal: 10% free
```

Can someone help me? I am trying to find what's wrong, im relatively new on bash scripting.

```
cat critical
2021-08-11 22:14:19,550 INFO  [com.optimization.ems.snmp.FnTrapReceiver] raw trap record inserted: com.optimization.ems.ems.model.snmp.RawTrapid: null, oid: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.2.14, time: 2021/08/11 22:14:19.547, sender: xyz1, version: 2, varbind: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0:5d 11h 0m 35s 350ms,.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0:.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.2.14,.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.1.6:xyz1,.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.1.8:Lost communication with device,.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.1.3:5,
2021-08-13 15:58:02,083 INFO  [com.optimization.ems.snmp.FnTrapReceiver] raw trap record inserted: com.optimization.ems.ems.model.snmp.RawTrapid: null, oid: .1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.2.3, time: 2021/08/13 15:58:02.79, sender: xyz2, version: 2, varbind: .1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0:98d 21h 39m 6s 60ms,.1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0:.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.2.3,.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.1.2:15:58:02 13/08/2021,.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.1.3:5,.1.3.6.1.4.1.2285.1.1.8:Memory usage is above normal: 10% free,
```

Comment: I suggest you use sed to extract the tokens.

Comment: Please post an example of 'critical file'

Comment: i posted the critical file example.

Comment: you are processing the entirety of `critical` for every line and ignoring `$line` variable

Comment: @jhnc how can i make use of the $line variable inside of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
while read line; do
    time=${line/*time:/}
    time=${time/.*, sender:*/}
    sender=${line/*sender: /}
    sender=${sender/, version:*/}
    description=${line/*.1.1.8:/}
    description=${description/,*/}
    printf 'Sender: %s\nTime: %s\nDescription: %s\n\n' "$sender" "$time" "$description"
done < critical
```

Output will be:

```
Sender: xyz1
Time:  2021/08/11 22:14:19
Description: Lost communication with device

Sender: xyz2
Time:  2021/08/13 15:58:02
Description: Memory u sage is above normal: 10% free
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this script. It is a bit of a hack and there may be a more efficient way to achieve this.

```
 for c in critical;           
    do      
    out="critical.outfile"; 
    outNew="crit.out "    ;     
    sed -E 's/.*(sender[^,]*).*/\1/1' "$c" > "$out";           
    sed -E 's/.*(time[^,]*).*/\1/' "$c" >> "$out";          
    sed -E 's/.*[0-9]:([^0-9].*[a-z]),.*/Description: \1/' "$c" >> "$out";
    awk '!r[$1]++' "$out" > $outNew;      
    echo >> $outNew;     
    awk 'r[$1]++' "$out" >> $outNew;
    cat $outNew  
done
```

**Output**

```
sender: xyz1
time: 2021/08/11 22:14:19.547
Description: Lost communication with device

sender: xyz2
time: 2021/08/13 15:58:02.79
Description: Memory usage is above normal: 10% free
```

Comment: :) better but its giving me: `sender: xyz1

sender: xyz2
time: 2021/08/11 22:14:19.547
time: 2021/08/13 15:58:02.79
Description: Lost communication with device
Description: Memory usage is above normal: 10% free`

Comment: Works perfectly for me. What you have there is the output of the `$out` variable file. I will edit my answer so there is a file with the output

Comment: it works only when there are 2 lines, but for more lines its giving again the same `sender: xyz
sender: xyz sender: xyz
time: 2021/08/13 15:58:02.79
time: 2021/08/13 15:14:19.572
time: 2021/08/13 15:34:19.549
Description: Memory usage is above normal: 10% free
Description: Lost communication with device
Description: Lost communication with device` :(

Comment: As mentioned, it is a bit of a hack according to the example provided.   It will fail at 2+ lines due to the `awk`

Answer (score 0):

For each line you use grep with, you can pipe to the echo command to output all in one go. Afterwards you can grep the time, and then the description. After the description you can use `echo` on its own to have a new line, before you start a new iteration of the loop.

For debug and troubleshoot more easily test the grep for sender sender, and see if the output is correct on the command line, then you can add this into the script, when the output for the sender is correct, the other two should be easier to amend after.

```
s=`grep -Po '(?<=(sender:)).*' critical| cut -d ',' -f1` | echo "Sender: $s" >>critical_body
```

Comment: Hello. I tried this, but it's not printing the value of the variable in one go, it only prints `Sender: ` . im checking